# Insecurity of Schnorr's Signature Scheme

Tags: cr.crypto-security

How is the Schnorr Signature insecure in the following 2 scenarios:

1. When there is no hash function used,
   s = k-x*m mod q   **instead of**  s = k-x*H(m||r) mod q
2. When a hash function is defined as H(m) **instead of** H(m||r)

Ref: [Schnorr Signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature)

Comment: This is a [homework](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~stasio/fall04/hmw5.pdf) question. Please note that in CSTheory, we only answer research-level questions. You can find the answer of your question in [Stinson's book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1584885084/).

Comment: @bala maverick, this site is for **research-level questions** in **theoretical computer science**, that are likely to have short well-defined answers. "Research-level" means, roughly, questions that might be discussed between two professors, or between graduate students working on Ph.D.'s, but not usually between a professor and the typical undergraduate student. It does not include questions at the level of difficulty of undergraduate homework. I am closing your question as off-topic since it is not a research level question.

Comment: You could submit it to the IT security site.  http://security.stackexchange.com/